# IPhone View is not loading after upgrade to IOS 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-4.2

I have looked around for an answer, and I see related problems on this and other sites, but the solutions do not relate to me. I have an app that was working just fine before I upgraded to IOS 4.2. Now the app does not load the view which includes an image background, and a collection of buttons and labels. The app has a timer in it, and I can determine that the timer is running because from another post I can show that the following methods are executed during startup:

```
SELECTOR: application:handleOpenURL:
SELECTOR: application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:
SELECTOR: applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:
SELECTOR: applicationWillTerminate:
SELECTOR: applicationSignificantTimeChange:
SELECTOR: application:willChangeStatusBarOrientation:duration:
SELECTOR: application:didChangeStatusBarOrientation:
SELECTOR: application:willChangeStatusBarFrame:
SELECTOR: application:didChangeStatusBarFrame:
SELECTOR: application:deviceAccelerated:
SELECTOR: application:deviceChangedOrientation:
SELECTOR: applicationDidBecomeActive:
SELECTOR: applicationWillResignActive:
SELECTOR: applicationDidEnterBackground:
SELECTOR: applicationWillEnterForeground:
SELECTOR: applicationWillSuspend:
SELECTOR: application:didResumeWithOptions:
SELECTOR: application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
SELECTOR: applicationDidFinishLaunching:
SELECTOR: createTimer
```

The view should have loaded. I am not getting any error messages. THe following is my applicationDidFinishLaunching: method.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    // Override point for customization after app launch    

    // set instance variable for view controller
    viewController.pressNumberNext = TRUE;
    // reset total and last value
    viewController.userTotal = 0;

    // clear status text
    viewController.status.text = @"";


    // initalize the number of digits entered
    viewController.numberOfDigits = 0;

    // disable interaction with status area
    [viewController.status setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    // initialize items for the tokenizer
    viewController.endOfInput = [PKToken EOFToken];

    viewController.randomExpr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""];

    // debugging flags
    viewController.debugSolution = false;       // debug flag to show solution under status


    // initialize the timer
    viewController.timeCount = MAXTIME;

    // timer should start running
    viewController.pauseTimer = false;

    // timer reset initialized
    viewController.timerNeedsReset = false;



    [window addSubview:viewController.view];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

- How does the view get loaded?  Via a nib, or via code in loadView?

  In either case, check the frame of the view.  Log it out in viewDidAppear:animated:.
- Also check your view's alpha and hidden properties.
- Are you doing anything wierd with the
  main window?  Is the main-window
  frame set to the bounds of the
  screen?  Is clipsToBounds set on the 
  window?

Comment: I am loading from a nib file. The view is of type UIView and so the viewDidAppear is not called. I checked alpha and hidden properties and I have a default background, nothing hidden. The main window is basic, Its just a background image that is stretched to fit and some buttons and labels. There is no animation or strangeness.

Comment: viewDidAppear will be called on the viewController regardless of the type of view.  If it's not being called that's a clue about why you're not seeing your view.  Try overriding loadView and/or viewDidLoad and set a breakpoint - is it being called?